# Need to connect to MySQL or MariaDB databases in QGIS 3.4+

Tags: qgis, mysql, mariadb

I need to connect to MySQL/MariaDB database tables where my geographic data is stored. I used to be able to do this in earlier versions of QGIS, but that option disappeared ~ QGIS 2.14. Are there any plans to include this option in QGIS 3.4+ or is there a way of connecting now which I am missing?

I've tried to use the plugin which seems to allow importing MySQL data, but I get an error during installation and the help provided is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

I still see it as an option in QGIS 3.8 through the add vector layer tool:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the visual, but that's not what I see in the Mac version.  The options presented for database are MSSQL, ODBC, ESRI Personal GeoDatabase & PostgreSQL.

Comment: So,  do some QGIS binaries come with the MySQL database connection and others  do not?  Neither of the OS X binaries offered by QGIS has the MySQL database connection option. Please assist me in adding that option.

Comment: I see a mention of this issue in GitHub (Datasource option MYSQL is missing in QGIS 3.x for macOS #34540), but with no responses. Isn't anyone else interested in allowing the QGIS macOS version to make a MySQL connection? It used to be an option in 2.x versions. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

KyngChaos QGIS 3.16 LTR installation material (and probably newer versions) has a GDAL Plugin for MySQL which adds the needed data source option!